# How to build a jar containing only dependency jars in pom

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, pom.xml

I am new to maven tool. I would like to build a jar containing only dependency jars in **pom** and also **parent pom** and deploy this as shared library in the server.

Could you help me out about the maven plugin and the steps involved to build this jar.

Comment: You can start using the Maven [`assembly`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) plugin, and then [`exclude`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html) your own project. I haven't tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 1):

The best setup for such purpose is to use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which creates a jar which contains all project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise. I used maven-shade-plugin and when done, I could see all dependency jars are unpacked and added into single jar. I want all dependency jars to be a jar within the main jar. Is this possible?

Comment: Jar in jar is not possible nor does it make sense. Via maven-assembler-plugin you can of course create a zip archive which contains all.

Comment: thanks for a quick response .. khmarbaise. So, my understanding is maven does not support building jar of jars. Am I correct ?

Comment: You can define the archive type jar in assembly-plugin...if you like.

Comment: <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Comment: I have added the above plugin to build a jar but it did not add the pom dependencies. Am I missing something here.

Comment: You should check the docs http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies cause the jar-with-dependencies similar to maven-share-plugin and not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just verified this on one of my projects.

Make sure that your maven installation is on your path and change to the directory that
contains your project using a terminal emulator or cmd.exe (in windows).

Run the following command:

mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

your dependencies will be downloaded to the target->dependency directory in your project

Comment: Hi uchideshi, I did this and I could see a folder "dependency" with all dependency jars available there. But, how can I make them as a single jar to expose as shared library.

Comment: Thanks for guiding! Here, I want to build a jar of dependency jars in pom. Hoe can I do that.